# Enable Pear SOAP module on shared platform

Tags: php, soap, installation, pear

I am transferring a website to a new server hosted by FatCow.  It is a shared platform and they have the Pear SOAP module already installed. I'm trying to figure out how to properly turn it on.  In my php ini file I have added:

```
extension_dir = ".:/usr/local/php/pear/"
extension=php_soap.dll
```

However I am receiving this error when trying to call a class that extends from the SOAP Module

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '.:/usr/local/php/pear/php_soap.dll' - .:/usr/local/php/pear/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I was told by support that Path to PEAR is .:/usr/local/php/pear/php_soap.dll

So am I missing something to enable the Pear SOAP Module on my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use fatcow for hosting and was advised by tech support that they do not support php soap. They do however utilize PEAR SOAP. I was also informed that with their UNIX hosting platform, they don't recognize extension=php_soap.dll command in the. ini file. Really ties your hands.

Comment: Yep, it took me a while to figure that out.  You can't do any low level stuff with FatCow.  I switched providers for that particular project.