# Emulate php_soap using PEAR Soap

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, soap, pear

I have Magento installed and would like to start using the API, however the Magento API uses Zend (Zend_Soap_Server) for Soap which relies on php_soap.

My provider does not (and refuses to) support php_soap, but does support PEAR soap and it is working properly (I have other web services operating successfully with PEAR soap).

So, is anyone aware of an already-written library that I could include to emulate php_soap using PEAR SOAP_Server?

```
class SoapServer{
    ...
    //Functions from http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php 
    // re-written to use functions from https://pear.php.net/reference/SOAP-0.9.1/SOAP/SOAP_Server.html

}
```

There are other posts on SO where others have experienced similar challenges, except installing php_soap is not an option and I'd prefer not to change providers over this alone:

- [Enable Pear SOAP module on shared platform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12063733/3424147)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a 1:1 identical SoapClient implementation in PHP userland code, which is possible but quite a task.

You might use PEAR's [SOAP_Server](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP) as backend, but it'll be work nevertheless.